# Log in page desplay

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I have one aspx page which have one dropdown list control, which have different types of products like Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4 problem is this if user select other than "Item2" it should move to login page if user is already logged in than he can continue. is it possible with Form authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the current signed in user information in a session variable?  That may be step one.  For the items not equal to item2, you could have an event handler setup on the drop down with an nested if statement to say

```
if (item.selected != item2)
{ 
     if(session(userloggedin) == "") 
     { 
         //Redirect to form login page
     }
}
```